# Conditional replacement of values in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes with seven descriptive data columns and a variable number of additional analysis columns (based on earlier steps in the code). I want to replace some of the values in the analysis columns of `dataframe1` with the corresponding values in `dataframe2` based on a Boolean value in the first column of `dataframe1`.

`dataframe1`:

```
structure(list(compare = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), ID_TREE = 29338:29345, 
    ID_PLOT = c(1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 
    1068L), ID_CATEGORY = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    ID_WOOD_SPGR_GREENVOL_DRYWT = c(28L, 28L, 28L, 7L, 28L, 28L, 
    28L, 28L), ID_BARK_SPGR_GREENVOL_DRYWT = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 
    18L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), ID_BARK_VOL_PCT = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
    10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), VOLCFGRS = c(3.21875, 6.576453125, 
    12.2406407654729, 0.863593268246, 1.15809306543472, 0.755301358016, 
    13.6662694477056, 4.549483421824)), row.names = c(NA, -8L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: (nil)>)
```

`dataframe2`:

```
structure(list(compare = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), ID_TREE = 29338:29345, 
    ID_PLOT = c(1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 1068L, 
    1068L), ID_CATEGORY = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    ID_WOOD_SPGR_GREENVOL_DRYWT = c(28L, 28L, 28L, 7L, 28L, 28L, 
    28L, 28L), ID_BARK_SPGR_GREENVOL_DRYWT = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 
    18L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), ID_BARK_VOL_PCT = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
    10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), VOLCFGRS = c(-2.32258333333333, 5.81718680555556, 
    12.2406407654729, -32.9676545519935, -27.9506018960536, -38.5047101237694, 
    13.6662694477056, 1.9138577595677)), row.names = c(NA, -8L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: (nil)>)
```

So far I have gotten the following line of code to work for 1 column:

```
df1[df1$compare==0,8]<- df2[df1$compare==0,8]
```

but when I try to abstract it to work for any number of columns I get an error:

```
df1[df1$compare==0,-(1:7)]<- df2[df1$compare==0,-(1:7)]
```

I also this and got a similar error:

```
df1[,-(1:7)]<- ifelse(df1$compare==0, df2[,-(1:7)], df1[,-(1:7)])
```

the two dataframes will always have the same number of columns.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share sample data with `dput` and the expected output

Comment: @mamend How about the number of rows?  Do they also always have the same number of rows?

Comment: @nsinghs  Yes, they will also always have the same number of rows.

Comment: @mamend your code works on my machine as is.

Answer (score 0):

Most simply you can "invert" your subsetting:

```
df1[df1$compare==0,8:ncol(df1)] <- df2[df1$compare==0,8:ncol(df1)]
```

Another option would be to `rbind` the dijointed rows together.

```
rbind(df1[df1$compare!=0], df2[df1$compare==0])
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the responses. The inverted subsetting did work, thank you! However, I also figured out that the root cause was that my data.frames were also data.tables, which is what was causing my original code to not work. Converting them to data.frames alone solved the original problem.